# Multiple javascript/jquery scripts on same webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slicknav

I have a responsive menu and responsive slideshow that requires javascript and jquery but only one works.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        prependTo:"#border-orange"});
});
</script>
```

The 2nd one works but the first one doesn't. When I switch them over, again, the 2nd one works but the 1st one doesn't. Is there a way to combine the code so that both scripts work or is it a case of "one or the other"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're including jQuery twice, just remove the second reference and you can have as many sections of `$(document).ready()` as you want to :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>

<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        prependTo:"#border-orange"});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very uncommon to use multiple versions of jQuery. Are you sure, that this is needed? Otherwise, try

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        prependTo:"#border-orange"});
});
</script>
```

If it's required to use multiple versions of jQuery, consider using `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Would this make it any faster? What is the difference between the top answer and doing this? Apart from looking cleaner I guess

Comment: There's no important difference. I just havent seen his answer, when i wrote mine :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple versions of jQuery use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var $183 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    $183(function($) {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
    });
</script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#menu').slicknav({
            prependTo:"#border-orange"});
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need both versions then you can use `$.noConflict()` for one version:

```
var jQuery_1.8.3 = $.noConflict(true);
```

Then you can use `jQuery_1.8.3` instead of `$` for the code that require jQuery `1.8.3` to work.

```
jQuery_1.8.3 (function() {
    jQuery_1.8.3(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
```

For the other version, you can keep using `$` as usual.